# Why is my API key triggering an error in openAI call?

Tags: javascript, axios, openai-api

The API key is working when I enter it manually in the object initialisation, but when I try to use a `.env` variable then an error is triggered.

This is what i've done and it doesn't work:

```
const APIKEY = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: APIKEY,
});
```

if I `console.log(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY)` it prints the correct API key. So what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Try `console.log(\`'${APIKEY}'\`)` to check if there is for instance an extra whitespace contained in your variable

Comment: There is no instance of a space or extra white space

Answer (score 3):

The API keys have a different format, as the error message says it's incorrect. All API keys start with `sk-`. Try checking if you used a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with openai key, until I found a correct format:

openai.api_key = ("sk-xxxxxxxxx")

The key must be in (), also it is a quoted string which you copy from your openai account. The string starts with 'sk-'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see that period at the end of the key in your error message?  Make sure that's not in .env.  I just had a similar problem with a semicolon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).